# How can I do scatter and gather operations in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, tensorflow, pytorch

I want to implement the scatter and gather operations of Tensorflow or PyTorch in Numpy.

- [`torch.scatter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.scatter.html)
- [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `scatter` method turned out to be way more work than I anticipated. I did not find any ready made function in NumPy for it. I'm sharing it here in the interest of anyone who may need to implement it with NumPy. 
(p.s. `self` is the destination or output of the method.)

```
def scatter_numpy(self, dim, index, src):
    """
    Writes all values from the Tensor src into self at the indices specified in the index Tensor.

    :param dim: The axis along which to index
    :param index: The indices of elements to scatter
    :param src: The source element(s) to scatter
    :return: self
    """
    if index.dtype != np.dtype('int_'):
        raise TypeError("The values of index must be integers")
    if self.ndim != index.ndim:
        raise ValueError("Index should have the same number of dimensions as output")
    if dim >= self.ndim or dim < -self.ndim:
        raise IndexError("dim is out of range")
    if dim < 0:
        # Not sure why scatter should accept dim < 0, but that is the behavior in PyTorch's scatter
        dim = self.ndim + dim
    idx_xsection_shape = index.shape[:dim] + index.shape[dim + 1:]
    self_xsection_shape = self.shape[:dim] + self.shape[dim + 1:]
    if idx_xsection_shape != self_xsection_shape:
        raise ValueError("Except for dimension " + str(dim) +
                         ", all dimensions of index and output should be the same size")
    if (index >= self.shape[dim]).any() or (index < 0).any():
        raise IndexError("The values of index must be between 0 and (self.shape[dim] -1)")

    def make_slice(arr, dim, i):
        slc = [slice(None)] * arr.ndim
        slc[dim] = i
        return slc

    # We use index and dim parameters to create idx
    # idx is in a form that can be used as a NumPy advanced index for scattering of src param. in self
    idx = [[*np.indices(idx_xsection_shape).reshape(index.ndim - 1, -1),
            index[make_slice(index, dim, i)].reshape(1, -1)[0]] for i in range(index.shape[dim])]
    idx = list(np.concatenate(idx, axis=1))
    idx.insert(dim, idx.pop())

    if not np.isscalar(src):
        if index.shape[dim] > src.shape[dim]:
            raise IndexError("Dimension " + str(dim) + "of index can not be bigger than that of src ")
        src_xsection_shape = src.shape[:dim] + src.shape[dim + 1:]
        if idx_xsection_shape != src_xsection_shape:
            raise ValueError("Except for dimension " +
                             str(dim) + ", all dimensions of index and src should be the same size")
        # src_idx is a NumPy advanced index for indexing of elements in the src
        src_idx = list(idx)
        src_idx.pop(dim)
        src_idx.insert(dim, np.repeat(np.arange(index.shape[dim]), np.prod(idx_xsection_shape)))
        self[idx] = src[src_idx]

    else:
        self[idx] = src

    return self
```

There could be a simpler solution for `gather`, but this is what I settled on: 
 (here `self` is the ndarray that the values are gathered from.)

```
def gather_numpy(self, dim, index):
    """
    Gathers values along an axis specified by dim.
    For a 3-D tensor the output is specified by:
        out[i][j][k] = input[index[i][j][k]][j][k]  # if dim == 0
        out[i][j][k] = input[i][index[i][j][k]][k]  # if dim == 1
        out[i][j][k] = input[i][j][index[i][j][k]]  # if dim == 2

    :param dim: The axis along which to index
    :param index: A tensor of indices of elements to gather
    :return: tensor of gathered values
    """
    idx_xsection_shape = index.shape[:dim] + index.shape[dim + 1:]
    self_xsection_shape = self.shape[:dim] + self.shape[dim + 1:]
    if idx_xsection_shape != self_xsection_shape:
        raise ValueError("Except for dimension " + str(dim) +
                         ", all dimensions of index and self should be the same size")
    if index.dtype != np.dtype('int_'):
        raise TypeError("The values of index must be integers")
    data_swaped = np.swapaxes(self, 0, dim)
    index_swaped = np.swapaxes(index, 0, dim)
    gathered = np.choose(index_swaped, data_swaped)
    return np.swapaxes(gathered, 0, dim)
```

Answer (score 13):

There are two built-in numpy functions that suit your request:

- Use [`np.take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html#numpy.take_along_axis) to implement `torch.gather`
- Use [`np.put_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.put_along_axis.html#numpy.put_along_axis) to implement `torch.scatter`

Comment: Thank you. These did not exist back when I asked the question. I'm gonna leave my answer, in case someone wanted to see the inner logic of these functions. Specially because the scatter method is a corner-case minefield!

Answer (score 4):

The `scatter_nd` operation can be implemented using `*np*'s ufuncs .at` functions.

According to TF `scatter_nd's` doc:

> Calling `tf.scatter_nd(indices, values, shape)` is identical to `tensor_scatter_add(tf.zeros(shape, values.dtype), indices, values)`.

Hence, you can reproduce `tf.scatter_nd` using `np.add.at` applied on a `np.zeros` array, see MVCE below:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution() # Remove this line if working in TF2
import numpy as np

def scatter_nd_numpy(indices, updates, shape):
    target = np.zeros(shape, dtype=updates.dtype)
    indices = tuple(indices.reshape(-1, indices.shape[-1]).T)
    updates = updates.ravel()
    np.add.at(target, indices, updates)
    return target

indices = np.array([[[0, 0], [0, 1]], [[1, 0], [1, 1]]])
updates = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
shape = (2, 3)

scattered_tf = tf.scatter_nd(indices, updates, shape).numpy()
scattered_np = scatter_nd_numpy(indices, updates, shape)

assert np.allclose(scattered_tf, scattered_np)
```

NB: as @denis pointed out, the solution above differs when some indices are repeated, this could be solved by using a counter and getting only the last one of each repeated index.

Answer (score 0):

Fore `ref` and `indices` being numpy arrays:

Scatter update:

```
ref[indices] = updates          # tf.scatter_update(ref, indices, updates)
ref[:, indices] = updates       # tf.scatter_update(ref, indices, updates, axis=1)
ref[..., indices, :] = updates  # tf.scatter_update(ref, indices, updates, axis=-2)
ref[..., indices] = updates     # tf.scatter_update(ref, indices, updates, axis=-1)
```

Gather:

```
ref[indices]          # tf.gather(ref, indices)
ref[:, indices]       # tf.gather(ref, indices, axis=1)
ref[..., indices, :]  # tf.gather(ref, indices, axis=-2)
ref[..., indices]     # tf.gather(ref, indices, axis=-1)
```

See [numpy docs on indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) for more.

Comment: In your solution, how do you define the dimension along which you want to scatter the src?

Comment: This is incorrect for PyTorch. Here is an example of the different results: https://gist.github.com/kylemcdonald/05f8c9aaef2cda9fe5bcfd74652db1a8

Comment: This does not do the same as the gather function as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46868056/3881984)

Comment: ... that answer doesn't use gather.

Answer (score 0):

For scattering, rather than using slice assignment, as suggested by @DomJack, it is often better to use the np.add.at; since unlike slice assignment, this has well-defined behavior in the presence of duplicate indices.

Comment: What do you mean by well-defined? My understanding is in PyTorch and Tensorflow, duplicate indices result in overwriting the values. In case of TF they specifically warn that the order of updates is not deterministic. I looked at np.add.at and it seems it is good for “scatter_add” operation(no?), but that's not the behavior I want.

Comment: "`add.at(a, [0,0], 1)` will increment the first element twice". What if you want to set the last value, like `np.set.at` ? but afaik there's no ufunc to just set. (Hack for X >= 0: `np.abs.at( X, ix, values )` .)

Answer (score 0):

I made it alike.

```
def gather(a, dim, index):
    expanded_index = [index if dim==i else np.arange(a.shape[i]).reshape([-1 if i==j else 1 for j in range(a.ndim)]) for i in range(a.ndim)]
    return a[expanded_index]

def scatter(a, dim, index, b): # a inplace
    expanded_index = [index if dim==i else np.arange(a.shape[i]).reshape([-1 if i==j else 1 for j in range(a.ndim)]) for i in range(a.ndim)]
    a[expanded_index] = b
```

Answer (score 0):

For Gather Operation: np.take()

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.take.html

Comment: `gather`is different from `np.take` as will be clear when trying to solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46868056/3881984) problem using `np.take`.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want the same functionality and not implement it from scratch,

[numpy.insert()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) is a close enough contender for the scatter_(dim, index, src) operation in pytorch but it processes only a single dimension.