# Replace torch.gather by other operator?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have one script code, where `x1` and `x2` size of `1x68x8x8`

```
 tmp_batch, tmp_channel, tmp_height, tmp_width = x1.size()
 x1 = x1.view(tmp_batch*tmp_channel, -1)        
 max_ids = torch.argmax(x1, 1)            
 max_ids = max_ids.view(-1, 1)
            
 x2 = x2.view(tmp_batch*tmp_channel, -1)
 outputs_x_select = torch.gather(x2, 1, max_ids) # size of 68 x 1
```

As for the above code, I have trouble with `torch.gather` when I used old `onnx`. Hence, I would like to find an alternative solution that replaces the `toch.gather` by other operators but gives the same output with the above code. Could you please give me some suggestions?

Comment: See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46868056/2476977).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround is to use the equivalent numpy method. If you include an `import numpy as np` statement somewhere, you could do the following.

```
outputs_x_select = torch.Tensor(np.take_along_axis(x2,max_ids,1))
```

If that gives you a grad related error, try

```
outputs_x_select = torch.Tensor(np.take_along_axis(x2.detach(),max_ids,1))
```

---

An approach without numpy: in this case, it seems that `max_ids` contains exactly one entry per row. Thus, I believe the following will work:

```
max_ids = torch.argmax(x1, 1) # do not reshape
            
x2 = x2.view(tmp_batch*tmp_channel, -1)
outputs_x_select = x2[torch.arange(tmp_batch*tmp_channel),max_ids]
```

Comment: Biut I need an operator from torch

Comment: @KimHee I have another idea, see my latest edit

Comment: Great answer, I think I will follow the torch.arrange suggestion. However, if I have `max_ids_nb = max_ids.repeat(1, num_nb).view(-1, 1) outputs_nb_x = outputs_nb_x.view(tmp_batch*num_nb*tmp_channel, -1)  outputs_nb_x_select = torch.gather(outputs_nb_x, 1, max_ids_nb)` , then how to use torch.arange as your suggestion