# Numpy Equivalent to "tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add" method

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, scipy

Question is in the title really, I am looking for a method in scipy/numpy/etc. (not TensorFlow) which encapsulates the behaviour described in the [tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensor_scatter_nd_add) but on Numpy arrays rather than tensors.

I have come across the [scipy.ndimage.sum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.sum.html) method, but couldn't get this to reproduce the example I've given below.

Whichever method you think fits has to be able to reproduce the rank-3 example that is provided in the TF Documentation:

```py
    indices = tf.constant([[0], [2]])
    updates = tf.constant([[[5, 5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6, 6],
                            [7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 8, 8, 8]],
                           [[5, 5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6, 6],
                            [7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 8, 8, 8]]])
    tensor = tf.ones([4, 4, 4],dtype=tf.int32)
    updated = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add(tensor, indices, updates)
    print(updated)
```

Hopefully someone has solved a similar problem before and can help here - Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this is duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46065873/how-to-do-scatter-and-gather-operations-in-numpy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do scatter and gather operations in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46065873/how-to-do-scatter-and-gather-operations-in-numpy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that the following function captures the desired behaviour for me:

```py
    def scatter_nd_add_numpy(target, indices, updates):
        indices = tuple(indices.reshape(-1, indices.shape[-1]).T)
        np.add.at(target, indices, updates)
        return target
```

Credit to Remy's answer on [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57254460/7861160).