# How to index an array/tensor on the "rest" of the indices given some indices?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, pytorch

Given some array (or tensor):

```
x = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
              [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

and some indices of dimension equaling the number of rows in `x`:

```
idx = np.array([3, 1, 0])  # Index values range from (0: number of columns) in "x"!
```

Now if I wanted to add a certain value `c` to the columns of `x` depending on the indices `idx`, I would do the following:

```
x[range(3), idx] += c
```

To get:

```
x = np.array([[  0,  1,  0,  c,  0],
              [  0,  c,  0,  1,  0],
              [1+c,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

But what if I wanted to add the value `c` to **every other column index** in `x`, *rather* than the exact indices in `idx`?

The desired outcome (based on the above example) should be:

```
x = np.array([[c, 1+c,  c,   0,  c],
              [c,   0,  c, 1+c,  c],
              [1,   c,  c,   c,  c]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a boolean array to use as mask:

```
# set up default mask
m = np.ones(x.shape, dtype=bool)
# update mask
m[np.arange(m.shape[0]), idx] = False
# perform boolean indexing
x[m] += c
```

Output (c=9):

```
array([[ 9, 10,  9,  0,  9],
       [ 9,  0,  9, 10,  9],
       [ 1,  9,  9,  9,  9]])
```

`m`:

```
array([[ True,  True,  True, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use Masking matrix to multiply by value you need only section that does not intersect indices.
Try this:

```
import numpy as np 

x = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
              [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

# initialize `c`
c = 9

idx = np.array([3, 1, 0])
#initialize mask 
mask = np.ones_like(x)
mask[range(3), idx] = 0 
mask *= c

x = x * mask

# output 

[[ 9 10  9  0  9]
 [ 9  0  9 10  9]
 [ 1  9  9  9  9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was tagged with [pytorch](/questions/tagged/pytorch), I will provide an alternative using [`torch.scatter_add`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.scatter_add_.html#torch.Tensor.scatter_add_). The effect is quite straightforward, calling:

```
x.scatter_add(dmi=1, index=idx, src=value)
```

will perform the following operation:

```
x[i][index[i]] += value[i][j]
```

So given `x`, `idx`, and `c`:

```
>>> x = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

>>> idx = torch.tensor([3, 1, 0])
```

Here is a one-line approach:

```
>>> x.scatter_add(1, idx[:,None], torch.full_like(x, c))
tensor([[0, 1, 0, 2, 0],
        [0, 2, 0, 1, 0],
        [3, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Wow, that's really neat! I'm assuming there's no such thing in numpy?

Comment: This is indeed not available with NumPy, a possible implementation is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46065873/how-to-do-scatter-and-gather-operations-in-numpy).